# How to disable form fields once record is created?

Tags: axapta

I'm new to AX and I still learning how to use override methods.

On a form similar to HcmPayrollLine, I want to disable all fields for each record after it is created. So after I enter a record and click new, the record I just created should be disabled/greyed out.

Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a new table? Should it work this way for all users?

You can set the `AllowEdit` property of each field to `No` leaving the `AllowEditOnCreate` property set to `Yes`.

Or you can override the `active` method of your form's datasource and add something like `yourTable_ds.allowEdit(!yourTable.RecId);` after `super();`.

Does it help?

Answer (score 0):

An easy one, just set the `AllowEdit` property on the relevant tables fields to `No`.

Comment: It won't let the user enter any data at all though. I just want it to be grayed out after they enter the data for the field.

Comment: Exactly, that is what "greyed out" means. If you wanted the fields to be not editable after save, but editable after an arrow up and down, then it would be non-standard behavior. Not recommended.

Comment: Right, what I'm saying is if I set it to AllowEdit: No it is not editable before save.

Comment: Sure it is, provided `AllowEditOnCreate` is set to `Yes`. It is a one shot experience of cause, as the user will have to delete and recreate in case of input errors. This combination (`AllowEditOnCreate` Yes, `AllowEdit` No) is BP for key fields.